# Trying to place rounded corners on buttons using jQuery Mobile and CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

CSS3 is

```
#hearitagain
{
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

HTML5 is

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

<p id="question"> The Terminator </p>

<label for="basic"> </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="">

    <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"> <input type="submit" class = "button" id ="checkanswer" value="Confirm"> </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"> <input type="submit" class = "button" id ="hearitagain" value="Hear It Again"> </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But I am not seeing the round corners....   I have been trying for the past several minutes but I am not seeing the round corners.

Comment: Google Chrome version 36

Comment: Should just work. Do you have any other CSS for that element? Maybe make a Fiddle to show it is not working.

Comment: I just tried with jQuery mobile and it worked

Comment: but it is not working on my computer.  I am using it with the latest jQuery mobile and is it creating some kind of a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile actually wraps inputs inside a DIV with the button classes. You can easily add a class to the wrapper using a data attribute on the input called **[data-wrapper-class](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#option-wrapperClass)**.

So create a class for the rounded corners:

```
.rounded
{
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

Then assign it to the data attribute:

```
<input type="submit" class = "button" id ="hearitagain" value="Hear It Again" data-wrapper-class="rounded">
```

> **Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8XG4v/)**